# Desempenho do operador ternário

Tags: desempenho, if

Recentemente me deparei com uma atribuição a uma variável booleana da seguinte forma:

```
bool varTeste = (varEntrada == 100) ? true : false;
```

Sei que isso é o mesmo que o código abaixo:

```
bool varTeste = (varEntrada == 100);
```

A pergunta é se **existe diferença de desempenho/processamento** ou o `? true : false` é apenas desnecessário?

Comment: Mesmo que exista uma pequena diferença você precisaria realizar essa operação milhões de vezes para se tornar relevante. Na maioria das vezes a clareza do código é muito mais importante do que esses detalhes, tente escolher a forma que torne o código mais legível e fácil de compreender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rigor, isso depende da linguagem de programação em questão, do compilador ou interpretador usado e talvez do ambiente de execução. Mas na prática, a resposta é **não**, pois qualquer compilador ou interpretador moderno é inteligente o suficiente para otimizar isso, transformando ambas as formas na mesma estrutura de dados interna (e portanto elas seriam equivalentes, o que e é quase o mesmo que dizer que a primeira forma se transforma na segunda). Obviamente, isso torna o `? true : false` redundante e desnecessário, mas o desempenho será o mesmo.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes de desempenho aqui. Levei em consideração o comentário de [Rodrigo Sidney](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/39671/rodrigo-sidney) fazendo muitas validações e a diferença foi realmente imperceptível.

Answer (score 1):

O ternário neste caso seria desnecessário e redundante. Fazendo um "raio-x" no operador entre os parênteses seria assim:

```
bool varTeste = (true || false) ? true : false;
```

Veja que mostra uma redundância. Em termos de desempenho seria imperceptível ou nulo, apenas uma pouca diferença em termos de *bytes*. Mas como a intenção é apenas atribuir um valor simples, *true* ou *false*, neste caso seria melhor usar `bool varTeste = varEntrada == 100;` (o parênteses também é desnecessário).

EDIT: A propósito, excelente comentário do [Rodrigo Sidney](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/39671/rodrigo-sidney).